# ERROR in The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

project uses angular 8

my project has a errors when run ng build --prod

```
ERROR in The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

Because I add "enableIvy": true, to **tsconfig.app.json** file

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
    ...
  }
```

And it makes this error
[image]

I find that this error is caused by my library angular I created.
I tried to **delete the my library**. It appears this error is missing and **my project can build success**.

Example import my library

source code my library https://gitlab.com/kawinpop/library-smart-ui-shared-libs

```
import { SmartUiSharedLibsModule } from 'smart-ui-shared-libs';
```

My project has never had errors when run ng build.

this project build errors becuase I want to **enableIvy**.

I am trying to solve this problem. All I know is I have to change the path

```
import { SmartUiSharedLibsModule } from 'smart-ui-shared-libs/lib/smart-ui-shared-libs.module';
```

**It make my project build success**

Why I cannot use my library path not work

```
import { ... } from 'smart-ui-shared-libs';
```

but work in

```
import { ... } from 'smart-ui-shared-libs/lib/smart-ui-shared-libs.module';
```

before I add **"enableIvy": true** to tsconfig.app.json file.My libraly still that path It work and can build

Answer (score 0):

You're missing "baseUrl": "." in your tsconfig, it's a must for "paths" to work.